# How can I increased the speed of insert huge data in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I have two tables in same server and same database in `SQL Server` ,name's one of them is (`Load_SLE_FACT_Invoices`)another is (`SLE_FACT_Invoices`).

I'm trying **transfer 100 million** records data from `Load_SLE_FACT_Invoices` table to `SLE_FACT_Invoices` .But unfortunately it takes around **97 minutes**.

How can I increase the speed of insertion data in `SLE_FACT_Invoices`.
Should I use special technologies ?
Please help me.
Even I use `Balanced Data Distributor` component but it can't increase speed of insertion data.

**NOTICE:After use `Balanced Data Distributor` I transformed data into one table(SLE_FACT_Invoices)**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not a solution but a workaround.

If you can do that, try to delete/suspend the constraints (primary key, foreign key, ...) that you have on your tables.

It can help to improve insert performance.

Before doing that be sure that the data are well formated so as not to have problems when recreate/reactivate the constraints.

Comment: Yohann thank you for your answering, I did this solution too,  i think `Balanced Data Distributor` this component made it too slowly execute, so i removed that but now it takes 70 minutes, even I used from buffersize but I'm going to decrease more than before.